# Is it possible to select random numbers from a defined set of numbers

Tags: c++, function, c++11, random

Random function usually generates random numbers within a given range. But is it possible to randomly select from a pre-defined list? For example i have [1,4,5,6] and i want to randomly select from this list only. If so, how?
Thanks :)
P.s:: C++ code would help me a big deal ^^

Answer (score 7):

The following code would help, instead of choose a random integer, we can choose a random index in the set;

```
int numbers[4] = {1,4,5,6};

srand (time(NULL));
int index = rand() % 4;

int number = numbers[index];
```

Here is a C++11 version utilizing `<random>` instead:

```
#include <random>

int numbers[4] = {1,4,5,6};

std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,3);
int index = distribution(generator);  // generates number in the range 0..3

int number = numbers[index];
```

Comment: I am downvoting, because this is tagged [tag:c++11] and I would expect the solution to utilize `<random>`.

Comment: @Zereges Thanks for pointing out. I added an `<random>`  alternative there, seemingly `<random>` doens't support selection from a list? or does it?

Comment: Also `rand()%n` is biased unless `n` divides `RAND_MAX+1`. That's typically the case for `n=4` but not generally the case. Though for small `n` and casual use cases that may be acceptable.

Comment: @persixty Good catch, I would keep that in mind for sure

Answer (score 1):

Good way to do that might be using shuffle. Basically, you shuffle array and then start to pick numbers one by one

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::shuffle
#include <array>        // std::array
#include <random>       // std::default_random_engine

int main () {
    std::array<int, 4> foo {1,4,5,6};

    std::shuffle(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::default_random_engine(12345));

    std::cout << "shuffled elements:";
    for (int x: foo)
        std::cout << ' ' << x;
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```